# cross product of vector A B C & D

Tags: vectors

how to prove : $A \times B \times(C \times D) = (A\times C) (B\cdot D)- (A\times D) ( B\cdot C)$; Where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are four vector quantities, $\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ is the vector dot product.

Comment: There's no better way to do this that I know of than just writing out the sums explicitly for the cross product (using the Levi-Civita symbol).

Comment: It seems like you don't know anything about tensors and you recently begin to study vectors... so, probably you are going to do this by the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Einstein's Summation Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Statement_of_convention), we can write

$$\begin{align}
\vec B\times (\vec C\times \vec D)&= B_iC_jD_k \hat x_i\times(\hat x_j\times \hat x_k)\\\\
&=B_iC_jD_k(\delta_{ik}\hat x_j-\delta_{ij}\hat x_k)\\\\
&=\hat x_jB_iC_jD_i-\hat x_kB_iC_iD_k\\\\
&=(\vec B\cdot \vec D)\vec C-(\vec B\cdot \vec C)\vec D
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\vec A\times (\vec B\times (\vec C\times \vec D))=(\vec B\cdot \vec D)(\vec A\times \vec C)-(\vec B\cdot \vec C)(\vec A\times \vec D)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Oh man... I bet he is crying right now. I don't think he knows what it means every symbol on this....

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the stronger result:
$$B\times(C\times D) = (B\cdot D) C -  (B\cdot C) D$$

Comment: Oh that question is 6 years old...